# I want to get the first string before comma on a csv file but also get the string for rows that have no commas (only one tag)

Tags: python, pandas, regex, csv

This is my original CSV file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtosi.jpg)

I want to make the genre column only the first tag. when I use

```
dataframe['genre'] = dataframe['genre'].str.extract('^(.+?),')
```

it gets the string before the first comma but it also gets rid of columns without commas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuuFD.jpg)

how can I make it keep the ones without commas as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different regex:

```
dataframe['genre'] = dataframe['genre'].str.extract('^([^,]+)')
```

Regex:

```
^       # match start of line
([^,]+) # capture everything but comma
```

Comment: It's useful sometimes, but chaining `str` should be avoided when possible. With more than 2, it's often faster to use a python loop.

Answer (score 1):

Close, but it's easier to split the strings than develop a regex in this case, because it's so simple. You can do this instead.

```py
dataframe['genre'] = dataframe['genre'].str.split(',').str[0]
```

Comment: This is not the best approach, it unnecessarily splits all commas. Also chaining 2 `str` methods is expensive.